# Is there a connection between Boolean algebra and probability?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is there a unifying abstraction that links Boolean algebra and probability theory?

Both Boolean algebra and probability provide us the means to answer questions about set participation. On the one hand, Boolean algebra is an absolute, binary view of set participation -- either you're in or you're out (0 or 1). With probability we can think of expected "degrees" of participation within a set according to a real-valued probability that spans between 0 and 1.

Is this about as far as I can draw a comparison? I'm interested to know if there has been work done to develop a deeper connection between a probability variable to a Boolean variable. Are there any sources that describe Boolean algebra as a limiting case of probability theory?

Comment: A boolean variable can be seen as a random variable with only two possible values.

Comment: I don't know if it is what you are thinking about, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Yes, seeing that made me feel warm and "fuzzy", har har. I'll have to read up. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @Dan you're welcome. Actually I rather wanted to link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set (which is the same idea but applied to set theory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at “Probability Theory: The Logic of Science” by Jaynes. He casts probability as an extension of logic, developing it as Boolean algebra with uncertainty.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox's_theorem

Comment: Highly recommended. This book made a lot of things click for me when I read it many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how real mathematicians would do it but I have a technique I use.

I represent the probabilities as binary literals and let the boolean algebra work as it normally would.

For example,

Accept some probability that a literal is true: P(ε) = 0.65
and then just plug that into the boolean algebra the way you normally would:
!ε.s + ε.!s = F

`ε s | F
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0`